# Ajuda com função Python

Tags: python

atualmente estou "desenvolvendo" um software em python e estou com uma duvida de como posso optimizar ele.
Minha dúvida é o seguinte, tenho que calcular notas de acordo com idade a idade e índices, Exemplo: A pessoa correu 2km e tem 30 anos, sua nota vai ser x, porém, se outra pessoa correr 2km e ter 19 anos, sua nota vai ser Y.
Atualmente estou fazendo com if/elif.

```
if idade == 19 and corrida == 2000:
     print('Sua nota foi: Ruim.')
elif idade == 30 and corrida == 2000:
     print('Sua nota foi: Muito boa.')
```

Gostaria de saber se tem alguma função que corte varias linhas de código, pois são varias outras atividades e idade de 18 a 60 anos.
Desde já agradeço a ajuda!!!

Comment: Qual o critério para a nota ser boa ou ruim com base na idade e a quantidade de km que a pessoa correu?

Comment: existe uma tabela(já estabelecida), quanto menor idade, mais voce precisa correr, fazer flexões, abdominais e barras, porém, nas idades de 20 a 22 esses indices aumentam um pouco, e a partir do 23 repete o indice de 18.

Comment: Já tentou fazer um fit com esses dados, excluindo os dados que apresenta essas exceções?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você sempre for comparar valores *exatos* de idade e de ano, a solução mais simples é usar um dicionário, em que as chaves são os valores que você quer comparar, na forma de uma tupla (simplesmente separe os valores por `,`):

```
tabela = {
   (19, 2000): "Ruim",
   (30, 2000): "Muito boa",
}

print (f"Sua nota foi {tabela[idade, corrida]}.")
```

Como é provável que você tenha várias "notas" que vão se repetir para *faixas* de idade e de metros - (por exemplo, a nota vai ser "ruim" para idade de "19" a "25"  e corrida de "1500" até "2500"), não é viável, mesmo na forma de dicionário, você ter 1000 entradas com as metragens de corrida para cada idade = 10000 itens no dicionário apenas para a nota ruim.

Nesse caso, a forma mais eficiente seria algo parecido com um dicionário, mas com uma estrutura interna de "árvore" que permitisse localizar um dado valor se ele está entre dois outros valores- e a chave teria só esses dois valores. 
Python não tem uma estrutura de dados dessa por padrão, e desenvolver uma pode ser um pouco complicado. Não seria difícil achar bibliotecas com isso pronto - mas aí entram vários outros fatores.

Mas, tendo em vista que você não vai ter tantas chaves assim, vale a pena uma outra estratégia: Um dicionário com as chaves, como acima, mas apenas com os valores mais baixos de cada entrada na tabela, e uma lista (na verdade duas, uma pra "idade" e uma pra "corrida", em que cada item seja esse valor mais baixo - assim, dadas as variáveis "entrada" e "corrida", em vez de usar esses valores diretamente no dicionário, você percorre a lista, e, ao encontrar um valor maior do que o dado que você tem, você pega o valor *anterior* e usa isso para buscar seu dado final no dicionário:

```
tabela = {
   (0, 2000): "Muito jovem pra correr",
   (18, 2000): "Ruim",
   (25, 2000): "Muito boa",
   # não escapa de repetir os valores para cada faixa de metros, por exemplo:
   (0, 4000): "Muito jovem pra correr",
   (19, 4000): "Boa",
   (25, 4000): "Super homem",
}

faixas_idade = [0, 18, 25, 1000000]
faixas_corrida = [2000, 4000, 1000000]

def obtem_inicio_faixa(faixa, valor):
    for item in faixa:
        if valor < item:
            return item_anterior
        item_anterior = item

    raise ValueError("Valor fora das faixas definidas")

def obtem_nota(idade, corrida):
     idade_base = obtem_inicio_faixa(faixas_idade, idade)
     corrida_base = obtem_inicio_faixa(faixas_corrida, corrida)
     return tabela[idade_base, corrida_base]

...
print(f"Sua nota foi: {obtem_nota(idade, corrida)}")
```

Esse é um código realista, sem muita preocupação com otimização (por conta das buscas lineares), mas que ainda seria bem performático para um máximo de 300 a 500 faixas em cada uma das variáveis. (isso pra uma aplicação web, tendo que responder dezenas de vezes essa nota em um único segundo - para uma aplicação mono-usuário, com print  e input, isso comportaria 100000 faixas facilmente). Para uma aplicação web de centenas de requisições por segundo, ou muito mais faixas, valeria a pena desenvolver a estrutura de árvore que citei anteriormente.

Como você está aprendendo, é importante observar duas coisas nesse código: o uso de funções para organizar algoritmos - mesmo nesse caso simples, tenho uma função que é usada para dois tipos de dados diferentes e o código é re-utilizado.
A segunda coisa é que não se deve misturar a entrada e saída com a lógica: o código que imprime os resultados *nunca* vai ficar dentro das funções que contém a lógica do programa - essas funções só localizam o valor. A "comunicação" com o usuário fica por conta de outra parte do programa, específica pra isso (nesse caso, um "print" fora das funções, mas numa aplicação maior, e funções específicas para imprimir valores - em aplicações Web, são as funções de "view", por exemplo).